# How can I make the status bar white background with black icon?

Tags: java, android

I want to make in my app status bar white background with black icon

Comment: Did you try on of the [light themes](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to make the icons **black**, but you can add these attributes to your activity's theme to get a white status bar with dark gray icons:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#fff</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Note that `statusBarColor` is api 21+ only, and `windowLightStatusBar` is api 23+ only, so perhaps you'd be best to put these in a `res/values-v23/styles.xml` so that you don't have a white status bar with white icons on api 21 and 22.

### Update

I've read elsewhere on this site that these attributes are not honored by some vendor-specific versions of the OS, including Motorola and Mi phones.

Comment: @SureshChandak What device are you testing with?

Comment: Mi Redmi 3s prime

Comment: @SureshChandak what version of android is it running?

Comment: Android marshmallow 6.0.1

Comment: @SureshChandak does your activity's theme derive from an AppCompat theme?

Comment: <style name="MainAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar